# Как узнать порты ,которые неиспользуются програмами

Tags: ssh, putty, порты

Как можно ,узнать порты которые неиспользуются програмами.Про команду Netstat -a знаю,столкнулся с тем,что порт который отображается как открытый,не получатся использовать в программе putty,так возникает он пишет ,что данный порт уже использутеся
 Server was not able to start with error message [Could not bind to tcp://0.0.0.0:135: Permission denied]

Most likely the port [135] you are trying to run the system is already taken by some other service.
Please find available free port and configure it in [config.php] and restart.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Чтобы использовать порты до 1000, нужно запускать программу от рута: `sudo (программа)`. И дополните вопрос, не ясно что значит `не получатся использовать в программе putty`. Также покажите что пишет `sudo netstat -ntl`

Comment: Cпасибо за ответ,пишет:C:\Users\пк>sudo netstat -ntl
"sudo" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.Я имел ввиду что ,хочу запустить приложение на хостинге,через ssh с помощью программы putty,и через какой бы я порт это не делал, высвечиваетя вышеуказанная ошибка.

Comment: Вы не понимаете как пользоваться netstat. Ее нужно запустисть на сервере, а не у себя на локальной машине. А судя по `C:\Users\пк>sudo netstat -ntl "sudo"` вы это делаете на локальной машине. Запустите `sudo netstat -ntl` на сервере и покажите что выводится. `порт который отображается как открытый,не получатся использовать в программе putty` - что вы хотите делать? Запустить SSH на не стандартном порту? Сделать проброс? Ничего не понятно.

Comment: Я скачал демо скрипт сайта,залил его на хостинг.Там две папки Server и Client .Я пытаюсь протестировать  этот сайт,следую инструкциям туториала,чтобы запустить этот сайт,нужно запустить  файл из папки server с расширением php. Сделать это нужно из программы putty через ssh соединение,и ,возникает ошибка которую я писал. Знаний в этой сфере не так,много поэтому я так неточно и пишу.Ввел я команду на сервере:n9534771 is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported. К вам если ,что можно обратиться за помощью на возмездной основе ,чтобы вы помогли запустить эту "шарманку"?

Comment: Если это шаред хостинг, то 135 порт вы не сможете использовать никак. Все порты до 1000 можно забиндить только под суперпользователем. На шареде вам никогда не дадут этого сделать. Выход: поменять в настройках порт на 1000+ (но и тут скорее всего будет облом по причине файрвола) или использовать VDS сервер.

Comment: файрфол windows я отключал,не помогло

Comment: Получается,что дело  в хостинге,где все это размещено?

Comment: Сервер на Linux сервере, правильно? А вы к нему подключаетесь через putty по SSH со своей машины на винде, верно? Тогда вы вообще не понимаете что делаете. 1. файрвол на винде вообще не при чем 2. на Linux сервере порты до 1000 требуют суперпривилегий, вы на шареде их не получите 3. надо либо поменять порт с 135 на другой, 1000+, свободные порты можно увидеть через `netstat -ntl`, которую надо запустить на Linux сервере, либо  запускать тот скрипт от суперпользователя через `sudo тот самый скрипт` - этот вариант потребует VDS

Comment: А как узнать на Линуксе сервер или нет? А команду netstat через что запустить ,Putty пишет -bash: netstat: command not found

Comment: Это просто. У вас написано `bash ...`. Баш - это оболочка Linux (либо FreeBSD, который похож на Linux, но не он). А netstat не стоит потому что это шаред хостинг. И его туда не поставить, нужны суперправа. Можно, конечно, попробовать собрать из исходников. `uname -a` выдаст информацию по ядру. `cat /etc/*rele*` выдаст информацию по дистру